# Prove that for any given uniformly continuous function there is always a linear function that is superior to it.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a uniformly continuous function in [0,∞)
prove that there are a∈R+*and b∈R that
 for all x∈[0,∞)  : |f(x)|< a|x|+b
I've tried manipulating the definition but to no avail.
I tried proof by contradiction but so far no progress.

Comment: Hint: uniform continuity means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Now take a fixed value of $\epsilon$, say $\epsilon=1$, and see where that gets you. (Furhet hint: an alternative, equivalent way of defining uniform continuity is to use $\le$ instead of $<$. In this case, it makes the algebra a little simpler.)

Comment: Question: isn't a linear function like $f(x) = ax$?

Comment: @Pspl In linear algebra, sure. In analysis, linear functions are of the form $f(x) = ax+b$, because 1) the origin isn't special, and 2) we want to use them as tangents wherever, at any slope. It's unfortunate that the two notions use the same name, but at the very least, while there may be confusion, they rarely actually collide.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you very much for your comment! I'm from Portugal and those notions are slightly different around here. I'm still learning the differences between the Portuguese Math and the English one, eh eh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon = 1$. Then by definition of uniformly continuous, we get some $\delta>0$.

In terms of $|f(0)|$, what value can $|f(x)|$ not possibly exceed on the interval $[0, \delta)$? What is the largest value $|f(\delta)|$ can have?

In terms of $|f(\delta)|$, what value can $|f(x)$ not possibly exceed $[\delta, 2\delta)$? What's the largest possible value $|f(2\delta)|$ can have? And using the bounds from the paragraph above, what do these bounds become in terms of $|f(0)|$?

Continue this pattern. Do you see a linear function that necessarily lies above $|f(x)|$?

Comment: I think it helps to fill each $[k\delta,(k+1)\delta)$ interval with 'boxes'. Might help visualize the bounding affine function.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Definitely, drawing boxes for where the graph of $|f(x)|$ is allowed to go will help. I did think about it, but I don't have a graphing tool here right now.

Comment: Ye, my comment was more geared towards Lazarus.